# How do you increase the connection timeout period?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I'm using the [Entity Framework Bulk Insert extension](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) because I have to insert a few million rows into my db.

```
        using (var context = new MyDBContext())
        {
            context.Database.CommandTimeout = 36000; // has no effect
            using (var tx = new System.Transactions.
                TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TimeSpan(0,2,0,0)))
            {
                context.BulkInsert(entities);
```

at first I was getting an error about a minute after the job was running, and that led me to try increasing the timeout on  the transaction scope, which I set to two hours.  After that I started getting a different error:

> System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException : An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.
>   ---- System.InvalidOperationException : Invalid operation. The connection is closed.

This happaned about after 10  minutes, so I tried setting the CommandTimeout to one hour, but that doesn't seem to make a difference because I still get the error after 10 minutes.

Comment: The BulkInsert extension method has an overload that takes a BulkInsertOptions parameter, which has a TimeOut property. The default value for this timeout is 30 seconds, so it's unlikely this is causing your problem, but it's something you might want to check out, just in case.

Answer (score 0):

You also should configure Timeout in MSSQL. With SSMS, select your database engine > right click > Properties > Connections > Remote Server Connections > Remote query timeout set to 0 infinite time or 3600 one hour.